# terraform init vsphere provider - Failed to query available provider packages vmsphere

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-vsphere

terraform v1.0.3 installed via brew on Mac OS

It's my first time using Terraform with a "vshpere" provider. When I do a `terraform init` on my plan, I get the following error.

```
provider "vsphere" {
  user           = var.vsphere_user
  password       = var.vsphere_password
  vsphere_server = var.vsphere_server
}

module "exa_v30_01" {
  source           = "../modules/vm"
  vsphere_user     = var.vsphere_user
  vsphere_password = var.vsphere_password
  template_name    = var.template_name
  vm_name          = var.vm_name
}

$ terraform init
Initializing modules...

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/vsphere...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/vmsphere...
- Installing hashicorp/vsphere v2.0.2...
- Installed hashicorp/vsphere v2.0.2 (signed by HashiCorp)
╷
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│ 
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider
│ hashicorp/vmsphere: provider registry registry.terraform.io does
│ not have a provider named registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/vmsphere
│ 
│ All modules should specify their required_providers so that
│ external consumers will get the correct providers when using a
│ module. To see which modules are currently depending on
│ hashicorp/vmsphere, run the following command:
│     terraform providers
╵

$ terraform providers

Providers required by configuration:
.
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/vsphere]
└── module.exa_v30_01
    ├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/vsphere]
    └── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/vmsphere]
```

How do I solve this? I googled and searched here, but nothing relating to VSphpere. Any clues? Thanks

**UPDATE:**

I see [Force Terraform to install providers from local disk only, disabling Terraform Registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63680319/force-terraform-to-install-providers-from-local-disk-only-disabling-terraform-r), but that's for a terraform version upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is correct. There is **not provider** called `vmsphere`. Maybe you wanted [vsphere](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/vsphere/latest) provider? Your module `exa_v30_01` seems to be using wrong providers somewhere.

Comment: Duh on me. I had a typo in my `vm` module calling for `vmsphere`. Thanks!